# Finding certain entries in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table made up of pandas data frames. It contains 5 different arrays making up the five columns of the table, each with hundreds of entries. I have another array made up of indexes from the array. How do I make another table containing only these indexes?

Comment: read this before posting; https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).